# ImportError: No module named 'dask.dataframe';

Tags: python, dask

I'm trying to run a standalone python script via "Anaconda Prompt". I keep getting the error.

`ImportError: No module named 'dask.dataframe';`

I have installed pandas using

`conda install dask`

I have also installed dask via:

`python -m pip install "dask[complete]"`

But i still get this error. I am able to run the script in Jupyter. i have also checked i don't have a script called dask.py

Comment: Why conda for pandas but pip for dask? What happens if you import dask alone?

Comment: sorry mistake. I'll edit now.

Comment: How are you importing dask into Jupyter? `import...` or `from <pkg> import...` etc.?

Comment: import dask.dataframe as dd

Comment: worth also noting that above import statement is a must. I was trying to call `dask.dataframe.somefunction()` in code after importing dask at the top and getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are installing Dask into one environment, but running Python from another.  I recommend comparing the results of ...

```
$ which python
```

or

```
$ which conda
```

and check your notebook environment by

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

I suspect that they are different paths and that you are confusing two differently installed Python setups on your computer.